# Where can I find an introduction to using DUnit with Delphi 2007 or newer?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, dunit

I'm new to using and writing unit tests, but I've become convinced that they can help me write better code and ultimately save me time. I understand that [DUnit](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/) is well integrated into Delphi 2006 and newer.

Does anyone know of any good resources for writing unit tests with DUnit and possibly an introduction to unit testing in general?

I found a [resource from Charlie Calvert](http://www.elvenware.com/charlie/conferences/2004/talks/UnitTests/FrameDUnitMain.html) which I have been reading, but I'm a moving pictures kinda guy, and I'd also like to see any videos related to DUnit testing as well (if they exist). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick introduction on Channel E:

http://channel-e.embarcadero.com/index.php?option=com_jvideodirect&x=1&v=gUNNLQi761kLo

**EDIT**
Above link is no longer current. http://forms.embarcadero.com/DelphiUnitTesting2-12 is a webinar on unit testing.  Description:

> RAD in Action: Unit Testing in Delphi Featuring Nick Hodges
>
> Watch Now
>
> Join Embarcadero and Delphi programming expert and author, Nick
>   Hodges, for an in-depth look at unit testing in Delphi.
>
> Without unit tests your code is fragile, hard to change, and
>   unreliable. Unit testing is the only way that you can be sure that
>   your code does what it is supposed to do.
>
> In this webinar, Nick discusses the basics of Unit Testing as well as
>   providing a demo that illustrates the points at hand using the new
>   DUnitX framework. This will lead to a discussion of stubs and mocks,
>   and the use of the DelphiMocks.
>
> Topics covered include:
>
> - What is Unit Testing?
> - Why you should be doing Unit Testing
> - Proper unit testing techniques including covering the "middle of the plate", the "outside corners" as well as checking exceptions
> - A specific use case  or unit testing using a real world example

Be warned - the video is over 2 hours long.  You can access it directly here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJsgLDjn5b4.

Answer (score 1):

Not a movie, but lots of screenshots and step-by-step instructions can be found in Delphi 2007 Development Essentials from Lulu.com for example. See http://www.ebob42.com/training/D2007Win32.pdf for the table of contents or http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/delphi-2007-for-win32-development-essentials/2673032 for the link to the paperback itself on Lulu.

Comment: First link is a 404.